# How to write a loop with async function as condition in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I want a method as below which will have a loop inside it to call the method isElementPresentOrNot. isElementPresentOrNot method will return either true or false. Loop will have execute until isElementPresentOrNot method return false or loop will automatically break after 15 seconds.

```
waitForElementHide = function (how, what) 
{
  while (isElementPresentOrNot(how, what, function (presence) {

  })) {
  sleep(1000);
  index = index + 1;
  if(index == 15){
   break;
  }
}

isElementPresentOrNot = function (how, what, callback) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(what)).then(function (element) {
      callback(true);
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      callback(false);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something that is already supported in webdriverjs. Check [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) and [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#wait)

```
const until = wd.until;
const element = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(what)), 15000, 'Element did not appear after waiting for 15s');
element.click();
```

## edit 1

Regarding your comment, you shouldn't be using callbacks because webdriver provides you promises to avoid callbacks. For example all methods like `findElement` and `wait` etc return promises. Your code could be simplified like,

```
const elementNotVisible = function() {
    const element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath(what));
    return driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(element), MAX_TIMEOUT);
}

await elementNotVisible();
//do stuff
```

Comment: Exactly I was able to do want I want by using Selenium Webdriverjs with function driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(element), MAX_TIMEOUT)

Comment: you shouldn't be using callbacks, I simplified your code, please check the edit

Comment: glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use async/await operators :

```
waitForElementHide = async function (how, what) {

    while (await isElementPresentOrNot(how, what)) {
        sleep(1000);
        index = index + 1;
        if (index == 15) {

        }
    }
}

isElementPresentOrNot = function (how, what) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(what)).then(function (element) {
            resolve(true);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            resolve(false);
        });
    })
}
```

make sure that node version is 7.6.0  or above

Comment: This is not required, all of this is abstracted for us using wait and until